# Javascript Form validator for Date

Tags: php, html, datetime, validation

I need help. This is my html code:

```
<tr>
    <div align="left">Please Enter Date:
    <td><div align="left" class="style66">(E.g: 8-Feb-11)<br><input name="userdateinp" type="text" size="20" id="userdateinp"/></div></td>
    </tr>
```

When I click submit button.. and the user input wrong date such as: 8-02-11, or Feb-8-11 the script must say that the user entered a wrong date format. How to do it? All I saw is pure number tutorial. How about the month saying FEB, MAR, APR, etc :)

I got this code from the net.

Javascript code:

```
<script language = "Javascript">
/**
 * DHTML date validation script. Courtesy of SmartWebby.com (http://www.smartwebby.com/dhtml/)
 */
// Declaring valid date character, minimum year and maximum year
var dtCh= "/";
var minYear=1900;
var maxYear=2100;

function isInteger(s){
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++){   
        // Check that current character is number.
        var c = s.charAt(i);
        if (((c < "0") || (c > "9"))) return false;
    }
    // All characters are numbers.
    return true;
}

function stripCharsInBag(s, bag){
    var i;
    var returnString = "";
    // Search through string's characters one by one.
    // If character is not in bag, append to returnString.
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++){   
        var c = s.charAt(i);
        if (bag.indexOf(c) == -1) returnString += c;
    }
    return returnString;
}

function daysInFebruary (year){
    // February has 29 days in any year evenly divisible by four,
    // EXCEPT for centurial years which are not also divisible by 400.
    return (((year % 4 == 0) && ( (!(year % 100 == 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))) ? 29 : 28 );
}
function DaysArray(n) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        this[i] = 31
        if (i==4 || i==6 || i==9 || i==11) {this[i] = 30}
        if (i==2) {this[i] = 29}
   } 
   return this
}

function isDate(dtStr){
    var daysInMonth = DaysArray(12)
    var pos1=dtStr.indexOf(dtCh)
    var pos2=dtStr.indexOf(dtCh,pos1+1)
    var strMonth=dtStr.substring(0,pos1)
    var strDay=dtStr.substring(pos1+1,pos2)
    var strYear=dtStr.substring(pos2+1)
    strYr=strYear
    if (strDay.charAt(0)=="0" && strDay.length>1) strDay=strDay.substring(1)
    if (strMonth.charAt(0)=="0" && strMonth.length>1) strMonth=strMonth.substring(1)
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        if (strYr.charAt(0)=="0" && strYr.length>1) strYr=strYr.substring(1)
    }
    month=parseInt(strMonth)
    day=parseInt(strDay)
    year=parseInt(strYr)
    if (pos1==-1 || pos2==-1){
        alert("The date format should be : mm/dd/yyyy")
        return false
    }
    if (strMonth.length<1 || month<1 || month>12){
        alert("Please enter a valid month")
        return false
    }
    if (strDay.length<1 || day<1 || day>31 || (month==2 && day>daysInFebruary(year)) || day > daysInMonth[month]){
        alert("Please enter a valid day")
        return false
    }
    if (strYear.length != 4 || year==0 || year<minYear || year>maxYear){
        alert("Please enter a valid 4 digit year between "+minYear+" and "+maxYear)
        return false
    }
    if (dtStr.indexOf(dtCh,pos2+1)!=-1 || isInteger(stripCharsInBag(dtStr, dtCh))==false){
        alert("Please enter a valid date")
        return false
    }
return true
}

function ValidateForm(){
    var dt=document.frmSample.txtDate
    if (isDate(dt.value)==false){
        dt.focus()
        return false
    }
    return true
 }

</script>
```

Then here's the HTML code:

```
<form name="frmSample" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return ValidateForm()">
                <p>Enter a Date <font color="#CC0000"><b>(mm/dd/yyyy)</b></font> 
                  : 
                  <input type="text" name="txtDate" maxlength="10" size="15">
                </p>
                <p> 
                  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
                </p>
              </form>
```

How can I edit it to make it.. 08-Feb-11? :)

Answer (score 1):

If you change the day set to always be 2 characters, i.e. 08-Feb-11 instead of 8-Feb-11 you could use a regex to check the 4-6 "tokens" to see if they are letters.

Is there any particular reason you are having them enter the date format that way?

It may be easier to use a more common format and then just have your javascript convert it.

Otherwise, your best option might be to do 3 drop down menus for simplicity if this is the format you must have, and then you can use php to combine the three results into a string in whatever format you desire.

Comment: Or use one of the already built calendar dropdowns to allow them to select a specific date.

Comment: Hi Eli, It was instructed to me that I should use the format 08-Feb-11 or 17-Mar-11. :( I dunno how to start. I saw a code but I dunno how to edit it..

Answer (score 1):

Dates are tricky because of all the formats. It isn't really clear whether you want the user to have a single format or multiple formats. However the Date.js library has some great functionality around dates if your requirements are more complicated.

http://www.datejs.com/

Also consider using it in conjunction with a date picker like jQuery UI:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

But bear in mind if a textbox allows user input you must assume that a user will enter junk in it. Datepickers will not prevent this.

Comment: Yes, that's why they asked me to make some validation that will say that "the format you've entered is wrong". I need to validate that the time entered by the user is the same as the current time in my system. How to do that?

Comment: I'm using http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ and it's useful and reduce my work. You should use jquery datepicker instead of writing and fixing code.

Comment: Hi, I'd love to use that but I'm not allowed to do it because they've instruct me to use the format they want. :(((((